# Fail when check is start another activity:

Tags: android, kotlin, android-espresso, ui-testing

When click button on `TradersActivity` start `JsonViewActivity`

I need to check is success started `JsonViewActivity`. Here Espresso test:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class TradersActivityTest {

    val context = InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().getContext()
    val targetContext = InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().getTargetContext()


    @Rule
    @JvmField
    var tradersActivitytRule = ActivityTestRule(TradersActivity::class.java)

  @Test
    fun itemList_viewJsonButton_click_check() {
        //scroll
        onView(withId(R.id.tradersRecyclerView))
                .perform(scrollToPosition<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>(checkItemCount));
        // click
        onView(withRecyclerView(R.id.tradersRecyclerView).atPositionOnView(checkItemCount, R.id.viewJsonButton))
                .perform(click())
        // check is start JsonViewActivity activity
        intended(hasComponent(JsonViewActivity::class.java.getName()))
    }
```

But test is fail:

Started running tests

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.test.espresso.intent.Intents.internalIntended(org.hamcrest.Matcher, androidx.test.espresso.intent.VerificationMode, java.util.List)' on a null object reference
at androidx.test.espresso.intent.Intents$2.check(Intents.java:194)
at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction$SingleExecutionViewAssertion.check(ViewInteraction.java:419)
at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction$2.call(ViewInteraction.java:282)
at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction$2.call(ViewInteraction.java:268)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use IntentsTestRule instead of ActivityTestRule.